# How to send request after changes inside filter?

Tags: angular

I have complex form with some elements like as: radio button, input , select list.

I need to send request immediately after touching one of others elements. For example, if I checked radio button, then page below is changes based selected filter  and response.

Exactly I can write one function like this:

```
function filter(){
   do request Ajax
}
```

And after call this method for all changes are happened in form. But seems it is not optimal solution.

Comment: if you just want to toggle element state (show/hide stuff for example) based on a checkbox, just use a ng-model on this checkbox and use its value elsewhere.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. I also do not understand what is so hard about proofreading your question title and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should user (change) event that belongs to any input.
Example:

In your html file:

```
<input type="text" (change)="filterFunction($event)" />
```

In you typescript file:

```
filterFunction(event:any){
   do ajax request
}
```